# Widget used in forms is not appearing on web page. Django 1.11.5

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I have forms.py

extensions/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import SipExtension
from xmpp.models import xmpp_buddy_groups

class ExtensionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    xmpp_buddy_groups_choices = xmpp_buddy_groups.objects.values_list('group_name',flat=True)
   # xmpp_buddy_groups_names = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=xmpp_buddy_groups_choices,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=False)
    class Meta:
      model = SipExtension
      fields = '__all__'
      widgets = {
            'xmpp_buddy_groups_names': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }
```

My model for extension app and xmpp app are below:
extensions/model.py

```
class SipExtension(models.Model):
    sip_extension = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    sip_secret = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    commlink_push = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
    xmpp = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    xmpp_username = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='username')
    xmpp_password = models.CharField(max_length=32,default='password')
    xmpp_buddy_groups_names = models.ManyToManyField('xmpp.xmpp_buddy_groups',blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s : %s' % (self.sip_extension, self.real_name)
```

xmpp/models.py

```
class xmpp_buddy_groups(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.group_name)
```

I want checkboxes in my gui as written in extensions/forms.py

But what I am getting is below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to pass an instance of the widget, instead to a reference to the widget class. Something like this:

```
widgets = {
    'xmpp_buddy_groups_names': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
}
```

Comment: Also, another issue might be your template. How are you rendering the form? Just by using `form.as_p()` or something?

Comment: just by using form.as_p

Comment: I am a Huge fan of you @Vitor Freitas. Your website is Awesome. Learnt a lot from it.